# Positioning disables hover selector and mouseover events

Tags: javascript, html, css, mouseevent, css-position

This jsfiddle..

https://jsfiddle.net/9e1wd245/12/

..demonstrates a browser behavior I'd like to understand better than I do.

If you remove the positioning from the crumbtray and the crumb, the hover- selected CSS is applied when the crumb is hovered and mouseover events are triggered when the mouse enters the crumb.

With the positioning in place, neither of those things happen; but if you hover over the *top border*, the hover CSS is applied and the mouseover event is triggered.

(In this situation, the approach used uses positioning to enable z-indexing so that the curved right border will appear over the left side of the adjacent elements.)

Note that you can take the negative right margin off the crumb, and the problem persists, so it isn't being caused by the negative margin.

I realize I could use an svg for a crumb, or maybe use a couple of separator elements over a shared background rather than using positioning and z-indexing, but why doesn't this work? Is there something in the spec that says hover and mouseover events aren't expected to work for positioned elements? Is there something else entirely that I'm overlooking?

html:

```
<div class="crumbtray">
    <span class="crumb">USA</span>
    <span class="crumb">California</span>
    <span class="crumb">Sacremento</span>
</div>
```

css:

```
.crumbtray {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;

    display: inline;
    z-index: -10;
    font-family: ariel, sansserif
    font-size: 12px;
}
.crumb { 
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;

    display: inline;
    border: solid 1px gray;
    border-left: none;
    border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;    

    padding: 0px 8px 0 12px;
    margin-right: -10px;
    cursor: pointer;

    background: #c3f4c6;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #c3f4c6 0%, #96f788 8%, #98e0a4 92%, #419330 96%, #188700 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #c3f4c6 0%,#96f788 8%,#98e0a4 92%,#419330 96%,#188700 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #c3f4c6 0%,#96f788 8%,#98e0a4 92%,#419330 96%,#188700 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#c3f4c6', endColorstr='#188700',GradientType=0 );
}
.crumb:hover {
    background: none;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.crumb:first-child {
    border-left: solid 1px gray;
    z-index: 60;
    padding-left: 2px;
}
.crumb:nth-child(2) {
    z-index: 50;
}
.crumb:nth-child(3){
    z-index: 40;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var ViewModel = {
    init: function(){
        console.log("ViewModel.init called");
        $('.crumbtray').on('mouseover','span',function(){
            console.log('mouseover crumb: ', this);
        });
    }
};

$(ViewModel.init);
```

Comment: "the approach used uses positioning to enable z-indexing" You don't need to position an element to use CSS z-indexing

Comment: Every reference I've read on z-indexing indicates that you do, including this one: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp, not to mention the spec itself, and if you take the positioning out of the fiddle, you can see that the z-indexing no longer works.

Comment: You are correct, sorry. Ignore me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work, because you've set a negative z-index to parent element (Why did you do that?). Just remove it from there or change it to some positive value, like 1, for example.

When you set a negative z-index to element, it creates negative stacking context of all children element, so z-index width 40, 50, 60 just make sense inside it's parent, but main z-index will be negative (under body element).

So the main problem is negative z-index, you can cut it and search some information with 'negative z-index hover' keywords to clear the situation

```
.crumbtray {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    display: inline;
    z-index: -10;
    font-family: ariel, sansserif
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

Comment: Ah, of course. The negative z-index was left over after my efforts to get the z-indexing to work, before I (re)found that non-default positioning is required to make z-indexing work. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: But why do the borders trigger the hover? Aren't the borders also part of the "negative stacking context"?

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is here:

```
z-index: -10;
```

This puts the element behind the background, which means although you can see it, the mouse can't "see" it because it is behind the (transparent) background, so it does not recieve mouseover events.

Now, it *should* still work, because the `.crumb`s have a positive z-index, above the background. It's likely that there is simply a bug, I do not believe this behaviour is documented anywhere.

Comment: Yep, that was it. It does seem a little like a bug to me too, that the body element, which is entirely outside of the stacking context, inteferes in this way. Even more odd, though, how the border gets treated differently, as if the border had a different z-index than the rest of the element.